# Cannnot locate Django new user sign-up email template

Tags: python, django, email

My Django application sends this email to newly signed up users - I cannot locate this email template within my files. Why is example.com being used and not my actual domain and why can I not edit this template or locate it.

Hello from example.com!

You're receiving this e-mail because user George Smith at example.com has given yours as an e-mail address to connect their account.

To confirm this is correct, go to http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.ca/accounts/confirm-email/odd2s0qikxm0ghdbzg573l2dlsmnilzr6v4wxtbxbbrmsp9khsi9p1fxtyxcstju/

Thank you from example.com!
example.com

Comment: example.com is being used because you're using the Django sites framework, and example.com is the name of the default site. Check out 'sites' in the Django admin and update the entry to have the correct domain.
Sites Framework docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/sites/

Comment: The reason you can't find the template is because it is included with a library (such as Django Userena?). You'll need to override that by creating a custom template and overriding the view class, specifying your custom template.

Answer (score 2):

You can able to change the domain name and display name through admin, default value is 'example.com'. Make sure you added 'django.contrib.sites' in INSTALLED_APPS list. For more details https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/sites/#enabling-the-sites-framework

[image]

Comment: The link is broken...